# tcsh: How to find out if shell was started with -c flag?

Tags: shell, tcsh

tcsh, as with other shells, accepts the `-c` flag to execute a set of commands from the command-line args (instead of from a script) upon running the shell, such as:

```
tcsh -c 'mkdir /tmp/some-dir; tar -C /tmp/some-dir -xvf a-tarball.tar'
```

Is there a way to query the interpreter's state to detect that `-c` flag? Remember that this flag is passed on to `tcsh`, NOT to the commands that were fed to the interpreter via `-c`.

Background: I found a few days ago that `tcsh -c "COMMANDS..."` still invokes additional rc files (in particular, .cshrc) upon starting up. I have some commands in .cshrc that I do NOT want run when `tcsh -c` is invoked (as opposed to interactive `tcsh`).

Comment: As an aside -- in bash, I would fix dotfiles being run in a noninteractive shell with `[[ $- = *i* ]] || return`. You don't need to detect whether `-c` was used if you can detect whether the shell is interactive.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh)):

> command (+)
> If set, the command which was passed to the shell with the -c flag (q.v.).

E.g:

```
% tcsh -c 'echo foo; echo $command'
foo
echo foo; echo $command
```